# How to create a View that shows a node from the URL inside the admin area?

Tags: 7, views

I have a certain node type that I want users to be able to view using the admin theme.

I have a view that provides a list of this content at `admin/foo/list`. I'd like to create a view with a contextual filter such that `admin/foo/list/123` would show node 123.

I can create that view, and it uses the admin theme, but what I'd expect/want is that the breadcrumbs should show `admin/foo/list`. Instead it shows just "home".

The View won't let me create a menu entry for it because of the contextual filter.

Comment: Are you using the context module?

Comment: Actually yes, i do use that